# Theta of 1 in big arrays

Tags: arrays, data-structures, complexity-theory

If I allocated an array of 1,000,000,000 members successfully, how can I access to member in index 999,999,999 in Theta of 1?
According to array attributes, an access for each member should be Theta of 1. However, isn't there some sort of internal loop that counts the indices until it gets to required member? If there is, shouldn't it be Theta of n?

Comment: What storage medium do you use? In other words, where is this array allocated? Random access memory, spinning electromagnetic disk, roll of tape, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no internal loop. Arrays are random access, meaning any element can be accessed in *Θ*(1) time. All the computer has to do is take the array's starting address, add an offset to the desired element, and look up the value at the computed address.

In practice, you are unlikely to ever have an array with a billion elements. Arrays aren't well suited to such large data sets as they'd be several gigabytes or more in size. More sophisticated data structures and/or algorithms are typically employed. For instance, a naïve program might read a 2GB file into a 2GB byte array, whereas a smarter one would read it in small chunks, say 4KB at a time.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually in theta of (1) only. when you declare `arr=int[100000000]`
arr var will store the first address of the memory allocations.
When you do `arr[n]` what it does is `*(arr+n)` directly add n to the starting address and directly access the array.
Arrays are always stored in sequence manner only.
for more info please read https://www.ics.uci.edu/~dan/class/165/notes/memory.html
ask in the comment for more resources if you need.